creating hierarchy from rows
the table 'accounts' has values as below:
CREATE TABLE as accounts (
le_parent varchar2(100),
legal_entity varchar2(100),
trans_account_parent varchar2(100) ,
trans_account varchar2(100),
accounted_net number,
period varchar2(10)
);
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('yayasan pahang', 'yayasan pahang', 'cash transfer','908B1-palang',300,'Jul-22');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('yayasan pahang', 'yayasan pahang', 'cash transfer','A2462-palang',-300,'Jun-23');
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES ('yayasan pahang', 'yayasan pahang', 'payment','a5365-loindm',500,'Jul-22');
query:
SELECT le_parent , legal_entity , trans_account_parent , trans_account , accounted_net , period
FROM accounts;
above query gives the below result :



le_parent
legal_entity
trans_account_parent
trans_account
accounted_net
period




yayasan pahang
yayasan pahang
cash transfer
908B1-palang
300
Jul-22


yayasan pahang
yayasan pahang
cash transfer
A2462-palang
-300
Jun-23


yayasan pahang
yayasan pahang
payment
a5365-loindm
500
Jul-22



i want to change the script to return result in the below format



account hierarchy
Jul-22
Jun-23




yayasan pahang




yayasan pahang




cash transfer




908B1-palang
300



A2462-palang

-300


payment




a5365-loindm
500




so basically to make it in the form of a hierarchy i.e one column for account hierarchy which will have le_parent as the top node then legal_entity then  trans_account_parent and then trans_account, i want the accounted net to be shown only with the trans_account with the relevant period as the second column also the data should be grouped by all four of these to have no repeating hierarchies:



account hierarchy
period




le_parent



legal_entity



trans_account_parent



trans_account
accounted_net



i can only use simple sql and not plsql.
i tried using unpivot it brings all 4 columns into one and case statement for the second column like 'case when period='jul-22' then accounted_net' end as jul-22 but unpivot does not convert it into a hierarchy.

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (NOT the output for your existing query but the data that is input to that query); and an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can UNPIVOT and then PIVOT to aggregate and then use a hierarchical query to descend the hierarchy:
SELECT account, jul_22, jun_23
FROM   (SELECT a.*, NULL AS ignore FROM accounts a)
       UNPIVOT(
         (parent_account, account, period, amount)
         FOR depth IN (
           (ignore, le_parent, period, ignore) AS 1,
           (le_parent, legal_entity, period, ignore) AS 2,
           (legal_entity, trans_account_parent, period, ignore) AS 3,
           (trans_account_parent, trans_account, period, accounted_net) AS 4
         )
       )
       PIVOT (
         SUM(amount)
         FOR period IN (
           'Jul-22' AS Jul_22,
           'Jun-23' AS Jun_23
         )
       )
START WITH parent_account IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR account = parent_account
AND    PRIOR depth + 1 = depth
ORDER SIBLINGS BY account

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ACCOUNT
JUL_22
JUN_23




yayasan pahang
null
null


yayasan pahang
null
null


cash transfer
null
null


908B1-palang
300
null


A2462-palang
null
-300


payment
null
null


a5365-loindm
500
null



fiddle

it doesn't work if i change the insertion order.

@AishaKhan Result sets are unordered unless you specify an ORDER BY clause and your question does not mention any requirement for a specific order. If you put the rows in a different order then you get exactly the same rows output (but in a different order - and since result sets are unordered then that would be correct).

@AishaKhan If you want a hierarchical ordering then use ORDER SIBLINGS BY with a hierarchical query (updated).
